# Joining samba server into windows AD domain, but in DNS subdomain

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba4

We have a windows AD domain, let's say **EXAMPLE.COM**.
With corresponding DNS domain **example.com**

I want to have just a normal domain member. Ubuntu 20.04, Samba 4.11.6.

Its DNS name is already established. Let's say it is **a.b.example.com**.

Forward and reverse DNS is already configured.
The commands *hostname -s* and *hostname -f* show correct values.

Now I execute:

```
net ads join --no-dns-updates -U some-admin-account
```

Everything looks ok, but computer is entered into domain under name **a.example.com**.

LDAP shows for this computer: **dNSHostName: a.example.com**.

The generated kerberos keytab has entries like:

```
host/a@EXAMPLE.COM 
host/a.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

Is there a way to specify full DNS name during **net ads join**?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are mixing up forward DNS names (like from websites) and ActiveDirectory trusted names (trusted server names, used in kerberos and NTLM authentication).

In the AD world, **b**.example.com is not the same as exmaple.com. It is a subdomain and (more or less) completely on it's own. The AD can carry a lot of them, nested or not nested. Thats why it is called a "forest". If you want the server "a" be a member of "exmaple.com", it is (and will stay as) "a.example.com".

But you can always add a additional (FQDN) alias for computers (given that DNS resolution is already set):

```
C:\> netdom computername <computer> /add:<alias>
```

You can enumerate active alisas of your server by typing

```
C:\> netdom computername <computer> /enum
```

And delte them with

```
C:\> netdom computername <computer> /remove:<alias>
```

Do not delte the default FQDN, which is also the CN of the object.